# What's the difference between the triangle/play button in VS Code's Run and Debug View and the F5 keyboard shortcut?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, mingw

I set up a hello world project according to this beginner guide:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
I have confirmed that the compiler tools are installed as directed.
I'm running Visual Studio code 1.81.0 under Windows 10.

Here's what happens: if I press the triangle "run" button under the Run and Debug tab, everything goes fine. A terminal window pops up containing the text:

> Hello C++ World from VS Code and the C++ extension!

But if I press F5 instead, it says "compiled successfully", and this happens in the Terminal sub window:

> (base) PS C:\Users\Ken\Programs\HelloWorldVSCode>  &
> 'c:\Users\Ken.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.16.3-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe'
> '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-0n02xe1q.y0e'
> '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-sd4ytaue.ji4'
> '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-ygq2mbyq.ivi'
> '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-hqish32t.fba'
> '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'

But in the Debug Console I see trouble like this, and no terminal window ever appears:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
( skipping gdb startup boilerplate )

Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 9704.0x27cc]
[New Thread 9704.0x40bc]
[New Thread 9704.0x4190]
[Thread 9704.0x40bc exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 9704.0x2e54 exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 9704.0x27cc exited with code 3221225785]
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. GDB exited unexpectedly.
The program 'c:\Users\Ken\Programs\HelloWorldVSCode\output\hello.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).

ERROR: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
```

So what's the difference between the triangular button and F5? And what am I missing?

Here's tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Here's launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you open your keyboard shortcuts UI and type `"F5"` in the search box and show us what you see?

Answer (score 0):

The should do exactly the same thing, at least by default. If you mouseover that triangular play button in the Run and Debug View, it should show "Start Debugging (F5)" (or whatever keyboard shortcut you have bound to the command ID `workbench.action.debug.start` (I have verified that this behaviour is as I have described (you may need to reload VS Code after changing the keyboard shortcut for the change to be reflected in the tooltip))). The default keyboard shortcut for that same command ID is F5.

If you're getting different behaviour, it could be due to an extension. You can check for that with the following procedure: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

You can also troubleshoot keyboard shortcuts following the steps in [the keyboard troubleshooting wiki](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues).